# Vector of pointers, cannot access element

Tags: c++

I am appending a vector of pointers to "Projectile" instances , stored in:

```
 std::vector<Projectile*> projectileInstances;
```

The following block of code assigns the vector "components" (x,y) to "projectile.projecVector".
I can then access this vector's element 0 with no problem as shown with comment.
I then append the projectile instance to projectileInstances

```
void Player::shooting() {

    if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left)) {
        std::cout << "Shooting";
        Projectile projectile;
        projectile.initializeProjectile(playerX + 30, playerY + 30);

        projectile.projecVector = components;
        std::cout << projectile.projecVector[0]; //no error here

        projectileInstances.push_back(&projectile);

    }
    moveProjectile(projectileInstances);


}
```

However when moveProjectile is called I can no longer access element 0 in the vector, I get an out of range error and the elements seem to have been deleted?

```
void moveProjectile(std::vector<Projectile*> projectileInstances) {

    for (int i = 0;i < projectileInstances.size();i++) {

        std::cout <<projectileInstances[i]->projecVector[0];//error here , nothing in element 0



        //projectileInstances[i]->x += projectileInstances[i]->projecVector[0];
        //projectileInstances[i]->y += projectileInstances[i]->projecVector[1];
    }
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: You're storing a pointer to a local `Projectile` which goes out of scope before you call `moveProjectile`.

Comment: `projectile` is destructed at the end of the if block, so the pointer you store in your vector points now to an object that does not exists anymore.

Comment: You'll need to allocate a `Projectile` on the heap instead, so that the pointer lives long enough.

Comment: Or use a vector of objects instead of pointers

Comment: I'll try to allocate to heap , @kevin I don't think I can becuase the vector makes a copy of each object but the coordinates of projectiles change so it will be storing outdated coordinates.

Comment: @Fred The projectiles are stored in the vector, if you change the coordinates in the vector like your `moveProjectile` function does then there is no problem.

Comment: Containers are at their very best when directly containing stuff. It's amazing how much more expensive jumping around in memory to find scattered dynamic allocations can be for a modern processor than copying small amounts of data around in predictable patterns in a contiguous data store. Plus all of the memory management s handled for you, and that has value beyond rubies.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys